# How to inherit from a model to use its fields but be an independant table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a CompanyRanking model:

```
class CompanyRanking():
    """Company ranking model.

    Rankin hold a top based on minutes usage for user.
    """

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.company',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='ranking'
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='ranking_position'
    )

    extra_data = models.JSONField(
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

I need to create another model with the same information as CompanyRanking but with an extra relation to another table (CompanyBatchByDate) in which I get the dates to  filter the users's points and show other ranking. I am trying to inherit from CompanyRanking as shown:

```
class CompanyRankingByBatch(CompanyRanking):
    """
    Company ranking model based
    on batch.
    """

    batch = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.CompanyBatchByDate',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='ranking_by_batch',
    )


class CompanyBatchByDate():
    """
    Company ranking model based
    on batch.
    """

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.company',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='batch_by_date'
    )

    initial_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Date when the batch start'
    )

    finish_date = models.DateField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Date when the batch finish'
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text='Batch that will be used to calculate the ranking'
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Name of the batch'
    )
```

Problem is, I want to be able to have a differente related_name of the relationship of user - companyrankingbybatch and want to update this model fields independently from CompanyRanking.

I have tried to delete the one to one relationship that is created by django because of the inheritance by adding parent_link = False.

```
companyranking_ptr = models.OneToOneField(
        'companies.CompanyRanking',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        parent_link=False,
        primary_key=False,
        null=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want is called an `abstract class`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

This will create this abstraction idea in Django, but will still create them as independent tables in the backend. You can test this to be true by looking at the migration file itself after `python manage.py makemigrations`

```py
class BaseCompany(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.company',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='ranking'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='ranking_position')
    extra_data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CompanyRanking(BaseCompany):
    """
    Default Company with default fields
    self.company related_name = ranking
    """
    pass

class CompanyBatchByDate(BaseCompany):
    """
    Default Company with changed related_name
    self.company related_name = batch_by_date
    """
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.company',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='batch_by_date'
    )
```